# `/home/airflow/gcs/data` is not accessible from DAGs after upgrading to composer-1.16.7-airflow-1.10.15

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

After upgrading to composer-1.16.7-airflow-1.10.15 via Web UI `/home/airflow/gcs/data` is not accessible from DAGs anymore: not as a file location (so adding space in the end does not help), and not as a Jinja template location either.

Either it is not mounted with FUSE, in which case how to mount it?
Or some permissions gone missing, in which case how to fix them?
Or perhaps it is possible to reinstall the whole thing?

**Update:**

I traced it all down to `airflow-worker` staying in the endless loop of

`Building synchronization state...`

`Starting synchronization...`

`Skipping attempt to download to filename ending with slash. This typically happens when using gsutil to download from a subdirectory created by the Cloud Console (https://cloud.google.com/console)`

`GCS sync exited with 1: gsutil -m -o GSUtil:parallel_process_count=4 rsync -d -r gs://us-central1-XXX-bucket/plugins /home/airflow/gcs/plugins`

until crash and restart.

Could be related to `gsutil version: 4.63` change `Raise error if final destination path ends with a delimiter. (#1273)`. But how to fix this in `airflow-worker` configuration?

Comment: I have tried to test it on my old testing environment and it seems to be working fine. Can you provide some code how you want to access it?

Comment: @vitooh it concerns all code that worked for years, see my update in the original post. So it is not about the code but about sync issues with `GSUtil`. Any ideas?

Comment: As I would review the bucket if there is something unusual there...I have seen already such error, and it was before v4.63, but usually it pointed some exact file. Are you sure this is whole message?

Comment: I just created another Composer instance because this one was unsalvageable. Apparently something went wrong during the automatic version upgrade.

Comment: You have to take into consideration that version upgrade is still in BETA.([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading?hl=id))

Comment: Actually the new instance created from scratch got messed up exactly the same way within 2 days. It seems that either this version of Composer (1.16.7) is unstable or something else is going wrong in cloud or GKE specifically since last Friday.